# With Excel 2013, How can I get the average of one column that is every 5 seconds averaged into every 10 minutes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

So, I have one column (column B) that records the DATETIME of each recorded instance. I then have another column (Column c) with the vardata. See pic attached:
[image: pic example]

I want to get all those varValues averaged every 10 mins, instead of every 5 seconds. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Add a helper column that creates your 10-minute buckets and then put your data in a pivot table.

Comment: 1)  You call it a time string, so its an actual string that needs to be converted to an excel time serial if you need to do any excel time functions?  2)  If you are taking the average of a bunch of averages, its not necessarily the same as taking the average over the same interval is it?  3)  how many 5 second intervals are there in 10 minutes?  Based on that simply use Average(B1:B_) and copy down.  Replace the _ with the cell at the 10 minute limit.  You will get a moving average over a ten minute period.

Answer (score 1):

```
=AVERAGE(C1:C120)
```

place that in column C1 and copy down.  You will get a moving average over a ten minute period in 5 second increments.

Alternatively if you want to grab the first 10 minutes and get and average of your averages, and then grab the next 10 minute increment then you could do:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C:C,(ROW(A1)-1)*120+1):INDEX(C:C,ROW(A1)*120))
```

When copying down and it starts producing errors, you have probably run out of data.

NOTE:  This only works if there are always 120 entries per period as its not looking at the time stamp but simply working with the fact that there are 120 5 second entries in a 10 minute period.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. if I copy down the next one is =AVERAGE(C2:C121) rather =AVERAGE(C121:C241) etc. Is there a way to get it to do that?

Comment: look at the second formula for that option and I think you want C240 not C241

Comment: yes you're right. I'll try out that second one, thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. I was wondering though whether @Stacker would need to choose a mid-point for the corresponding time for the average in your second formula - something like =INDEX(A:A,ROW(A1)*120-59), or just the first time =INDEX(A:A,ROW(A1)*120-119) .

Comment: @TomSharpe not checking your numbers, but yes one could always off set the range doing something like that.  Though I thought he wanted the averages of what is in the B column, not the A column. DOH I just realized that his image is not column A and column B...adjusting my formulas now..

Comment: You're right, so the formulae in my comment should have referred to column B not A as well.

Comment: I wont be able to check this out until this evening, will get back to you